# Send helper additional class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In a rails 4 app, I'm trying to pass a default option to the text_field helper, but seem to be stuck on how to implement this.

So far, I have in my view:

```
<%= new_text_field :name, class: "", placeholder: "" %>
```

and in my application_helper.rb

```
def new_text_field(object_name, method, options = {})
   text_field(object_name, method, options = {}) # Trying to pass in a default class here, for example ".bigger"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def new_text_field(object_name, method = nil, options = {})
  options[:class] ||= 'bigger' # this will set bigger as default value if "class" option isn't passed
  text_field(object_name, method, options = {})
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
def new_text_field_tag(name, value=nil, options)
  your_class = "bigger"

  if options.has_key?(:class)
    options[:class] += " #{your_class}"
  else
    options[:class] = your_class
  end

  text_field_tag(name, value, options)
end
```